# Selenium css >> locate by color

Tags: css, selenium

Can anyone advise, how to verify specific color using css?

I can do it with xpath locator. But I cannot with css.

This is xpath locator which is working:

```
//div[10][@style="background-color: rgb(255, 76, 219);"]
```

Comment: you seem to get some weird requirements from the managers ;)

Comment: No, there is a testcase for which we need to verify that the selected color is present on page.

Comment: This a part of code from source: </div></div><div class="shc" style="background-color:#814c1b;">About Me</div>

Comment: please help if someone knows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [getCssValue](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
String backgroundColor = element.getCssValue("background-color");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just starting with Selenium myself. Awesome testing tool!

Did some searching and found: `//tr[@bgcolor/text()="tan"]`

Perhaps you can do: `//div[10][@bgcolor/text()="#814c1b"]`

src: http://old.nabble.com/Using-Selenium-to-find-a-row-based-on-it's-background-color-td24859281.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with CSS locators, AFAIK.

Your best best to avoid XPath is a gnarly DOM locator like:

```
dom=(var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); var targets = []; for (div in divs) { if (divs.hasOwnProperty(div) && div.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 76, 219)') targets.push(div); })
```

You might consider testing for a given selector instead, like:

```
css=div.red
```

Answer (score 0):

Once look at this,It may solve your problem

[Get color attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135080/get-color-attribute-from-the-styles-table/8135474#comment14252057_8135474)