# Get color attribute from the styles table

Tags: css, selenium, getattribute

I need to verify the value of background color of div. Here's the HTML:

```html
<div id="outercontainer" align="left">
```

The information about background color is defined in file style.css like so:

```
#outercontainer {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I tried to get the value of bgcolor using `selenium.getattribute` command, but selenium returned me following error message :

> ERROR: Could not find element attribute: css=#oute
>   rcontainer@background-color on session
>   bc60eb07f15e4e63986634fb59bf58a1

as the result.
This part of my code:

```cs
try
{
     string atr_str = selenium.GetAttribute("css=#outercontainer@background-color");
     Console.WriteLine(atr_str);
}
catch (SeleniumException)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Color value was not got.");
}
```

In fact I tried different ways with different types of locators, but nothing helped me.
What can you advise to do?

Comment: You can't use CSS locators to access an element's style attributes.

Comment: But can you tell me the right way? I'm novice in web-development QA

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a C# environment to test it in, but something like this should work:

```
string js = "
    window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(
        window.document.getElementById('outercontainer'), null).
            getPropertyValue('background-color');
            ";
string res = selenium.GetEval(js);
```

Now `res` will contain the `rgba` value of the background color. You will have to use Javascript since Selenium doesn't work on the computed styles, only on the styles defined in the HTML tags themselves.

I played with the linebreaks a bit to keep things readable: the `js` string can all be put on a single line.

Comment: Thank you. I used this way. It works. By the the way it solves some other problems, I've got in my work.

Comment: +1 cause the OP didn't choose your answer and it was the correct answer

Comment: i have given background-color as #730606 . and i am getting the result as  res="rgb(115, 6, 6)". how to compare these two values? so that we can verify whether the given color is correct or not?

Comment: As a side note, this won't work for IE6,7,8. [Here's how to overcome it.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html). And about that colour comparing - your original is in HEX, your new is in normal decimal, so you'll want the first one to convert to decimal, too (or the other way around - your pick).

Comment: am using firefox 12. and how can i convert color from hex to rgd?? i can get the rgd value from [here](http://www.easycalculation.com/color-coder.php) and i can use it manually. but is their any way to convert the color automatically ? in selenium...

Comment: [Oh, c'mon.](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23%20hexadecimal%20to%20decimal) You must have heard of RGB color coding and hexadecimal numbers. [You can do it!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) There's definitely a lot of tools for it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
string rgbaColor = yourElement.GetCssValue("background-color");
```