# How to verify bold appearance of a certain field in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate a manual script (using selenium in java) to check the bold appearance of a certain field(label:which stands for mandatory field) on a web page . what can be the possible selenium java functions to verify the bold appearance of certain element(In class there is no information about the appearance)

Comment: And once again: please add some code. You can check if element containing the text has any class responsible for formatting the text.

Comment: The firebug inspection for the label: Currency on my page  is
<div class="column1 column_text label_required"> Currency: </div>
ahead of it is the dropdown to select currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [font-weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) using the `style()` method (assuming you are actually using Selenium-Webdriver).

So say you have HTML like:

```
<body>
  <div id='1' style='font-weight:normal'>
    <div id='2' style='font-weight:bold'>Field Label</div>
    <div id='3'>Field</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can do the following to check the font-weight of the field label div (the following is in Ruby, though similar should be possible in the other languages).

```
el = driver.find_element(:id, "2")
if el.style('font-weight') >= 700
  puts 'text is bold'
else
  puts 'text is not bold'
end
```

Answer (score 8):

With WebDriver (in Java), you can use [getCssValue()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29).

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
(...)

// assuming elem is a healthy WebElement instance, your found element
String fontWeight = elem.getCssValue("font-weight");
assertTrue(fontWeight.equals("bold") || fontWeight.equals("700"));
```

[(since `700` is the same as `bold`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight)

---

With Selenium RC, see [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135080/get-color-attribute-from-the-styles-table), just use `font-weight` (or `fontWeight` depending on the usage).

Answer (score 2):

I really do like Justin Ko's suggestion to use the `style("font-weight")` method, however in the python bindings, the equivalent appears to be `value_of_css_property("font-weight")`

```
>>> element = self.wd.find_element_by_id("some-id")
>>> element.value_of_css_property('font-weight')
u'700'
>>> element.style('font-weight')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'style'
```

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#132

apologies that this is a separate answer versus a comment for that answer, but I apparently have too low of a karma threshold to comment there

Answer (score 0):

I see that the element you mention has a compound class, why not try to locate all the elements with the label_required class, python example

```
els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(div[class*=label_required])
self.assertTrue(len(els) == [known value of required fields on page])
```

java(Note: I don't write java code, so syntax may be wrong):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement els=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class*=label_required]"));
assertTrue(els.length == [known value of required fields on page]);
```

Comment: I am writing scripts in java to be executed by testng . Can u please provide me java code(selenium) for it

Comment: i added to my initial comment, please mark as answer if this works for you, thanks