# Stop the selenium server until File uploaded

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using a file upload task with Selenium.

The problem here is, to upload file, it is taking 5-10 seconds time. But i have to stop the Selenium server until it uploaded completely.

Here is some example code.

```
selenium.type("id=Fileuploader","c:\\mypic.jpg");
selenium.click("id=submmit");
```

It is giving error because the `selenium.click` statement is executing right after the `selenium.type` statement without waiting for the file to upload fully.

So, what should I use here to stop the Selenium server (server has to wait for sometime)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous requests are always hard to track. There must be some change on the page when the file is uploaded, so look for it, wait for it.

You can try [waitForCondition()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#waitForCondition%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Or some sort of [isElementPresent()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#isElementPresent%28java.lang.String%29) magic

```
final int TIMEOUT = 10000;  // ten seconds
long targetTime = System.currentTimeInMillis() + TIMEOUT;
while((System.currentTimeInMillis() < targetTime)) {
    if (selenium.isElementPresent("xpath=something")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: If there's no new element, there has to be at least some sort of change. For example, if your asynchronous upload changes a `value` of some hidden `input` element, you could test for it using [getValue()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29), or maybe just a smart locator:

```
isElementPresent("xpath=//input[@type='hidden' and contains(@value,'mypic.jpg')]");
```

**EDIT2**: If the element for which we check (in this case, picture preview) is present even before the upload, then it was just not visible and we can test that by [isVisible()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#isVisible%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: i tried with `selenium.iselementpresent`. But there is no new element,which is coming after fie uploaded successfully.

Comment: I dint yet get the solution for yesterday's question.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. I still think there has to be some other undiscovered element or script, since you can't click on `<input type="hidden" />` elements in your browser.

Comment: Anyway, do you get the way to check for changes on page? If there's no new element, there has to be a change. If there's no change, either, and the file is uploaded silently, then `Thread.sleep()` is your only hope.

Comment: There is a change, after uploading the file. If we upload a image, after uploading completes, a new preview element is coming at right side. i tried `selenium.iselementpresent("xpath of preview element")`. Actually that preview is a div element which is visible after uploading the imaga

Comment: But the problem here is `selenium.iselementpresent("xpath of preview element")` returning true always. Before uploading the file also it is returning true. But it is invisible before uploading. After uploading only it is visible. So, i am not getting why it is returning true before uploading

Comment: [isVisible()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#isVisible%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10002/discussion-between-ranadheer-and-slanec)

Comment: Not really, A LOT of work is on me now. But email me to JanecekPetr at seznam dot cz, if you want. I'll have a quick look on your new questions, too .)

Comment: Hi Slanec. I am taken as a developer into the company and now they are asking me to do testing. Which is better ? Testing or Development ? Is Automation testing is demanding ? or should i go for developement only ? I can't decide. pls Help

Comment: Here, in Czech Republic, developers usually don't want to do any sort of testing. Writing unit tests is annoying and manual testers (those who just sit tight and click something the whole day) don't have to be good programmers. That said, Selenium is neither unit testing tool nor "manual" testing and a lot of actual programming is involved. If you feel to be a programmer, then anything that helps you get experience is good for you. Being a Selenium specialist could be demanded a lot. Being a good developer is demanded for sure. Avoid testing as in "read a test case and spend 8 hours clicking"

Comment: So, shall i continue with this selenium testing(automation testing) ?? i am bothered about future. means does automation tester has good life?

Comment: Man, I can't take this call for you. I'm practically your age, I'm a student just like you and I don't know anything about jobs in your country. I guess it's not bad to be a selenium expert :). Anything that gives you fun, money and experience is good!

Comment: can you see this question. and see my comment. i have a issue.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135080/get-color-attribute-from-the-styles-table/8135474#comment14252057_8135474)

Answer (score 1):

If worst, you can always use some `Thread.sleep()` in the code. But the best way is to see the [advanced usage - explicit and implicit waiting](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: Which is not for good old selenium, I fear. You would have to either switch to `WebDriver`, or at least try to use [`SeleniumBackedWebDriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverBackedSelenium.html).

Comment: is it safe to use thread.sleep in all the cases? means whenever need  to wait for some element to appear/visible, am using a for/while loop. Now, can i replace those loops with thread.sleep(some time) ??

Comment: Thats why my answer begins "If worst" ... No, its not always safe. But also, it does not mean that you should never use it ;)

Comment: yup. See the link I posted in the answer - thats the proper way (my own opinion) how to achieve it. And if it still does not help, then I would use some sleeps. But also, I am really bad programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the file, new element is coming which showing the preview of the uploaded element.

So, i used

```
selenium.isVisible("xpath of new preview element")
```

Put it in loop. It will work.

Thank you.