# How to get color of label field using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a form using selenium web driver. When I enter invalid username the color of username label field changes to red. I want to get the color of that label field using selenium to find out weather the color of label is turned to red or not

Comment: Find the attribute of that color. Can you paste the html ?

Answer (score 2):

Please do it like below:

1.For any tag first do a inspect element on it via developers mode console will display a developers window divided into two parts

2.one window in the left shows HTML source code for the tag and other window right bottom of the screen shows CSS associated with that HTML source code

3.under Style tag we can view CSS associated with the currently selected tag

Now the Webdriver code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http:url/Login.html");

        // identifying color before entering any value inside the input box
        String visibilityBefore =driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).getCssValue("border-bottom-color");
        // print that value 
        System.out.println(visibilityBefore);  // prints rgba(223, 223, 223, 1)
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // click the login button without entering any value inside the 
        // user name and password to make red border come into action

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // identifying color after clicking the login button
        String visibilityAfter =driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).getCssValue("border-bottom-color");
        System.out.println(visibilityAfter); // prints rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)
    }
```

Please find the sample snapshot for a clear visibility:

[image]

For more help, please also look at [How to Using Webdriver Selenium to get the value of "style" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452790/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-to-get-the-value-of-style-element)

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution worked for me. I got the output rgba(255,0,0,1). Same as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The color of the element is most likely controlled by a CSS class, which will apply a style to that element.  This means that you could either just verify that the element has that particular style applied, or you can get the CSS value of the background color (presumably this is what's turned red).  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135080/get-color-attribute-from-the-styles-table) may be helpful to you.